# how to avoid The file already exists error in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

```
Private Shared Sub CopyDirectory(sourcePath As String, destPath As String)
        If Not Directory.Exists(destPath) Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(destPath)
        End If

    For Each file__1 As String In Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath)
        Dim dest As String = Path.Combine(destPath, Path.GetFileName(file__1))
        Try
            File.Copy(file__1, dest)    '<--------this part is showing error
        Catch ex As Exception
            File.Replace(file__1, dest, dest, 0)
        End Try
    Next

    For Each folder As String In Directory.GetDirectories(sourcePath)
        Dim dest As String = Path.Combine(destPath, Path.GetFileName(folder))
        CopyDirectory(folder, dest)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You're trying to copy a file that already exists in the same directory. Change the destination directory or change the file name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use overload of `File.Copy` method passing `True` as third parameter :

```
File.Copy(file__1, dest, True)
```

That will replace existing file in destination folder if any, instead of throwing exception.

Reference : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx